# SQL query that has sum column based on other records being 'similar' (within a range)

Tags: sql, oracle

For some reason my brain can't comprehend this. I have a 'record' table that has columns: id, name, genre, date, channel

I want to do a query that will return every record in the table, but also another column that has the sum of all the records with the same genre and day (of date) and channel (within .0005) as the current record. Hopefully that makes sense. I will try to illustrate:

Table: `record`

```
id        name        genre       date          Channel            
1         Scott       rock        2014-01-21    30.0345
2         Jim         rap         2014-01-21    55.0000
3         Dave        country     2014-01-22    23.0000
4         Tim         rock        2014-01-22    25.0000
5         Dave        rock        2014-01-21    34.0350
6         John        rock        2014-03-24    23.0000
7         Stan        rap         2013-09-16    14.0000
8         Jake        country     2014-01-21    30.0000
9         Mike        country     2014-01-22    22.9995
10        Jodi        country     2015-01-22    23.0006
11        Jodi        country     2015-01-22    23.0004
```

This is what I want my query to return:

```
id        name        genre       date        Channel  same_day_count
1         Scott       rock        2014-01-21  30.0345  2 
2         Jim         rap         2014-01-21  55.0000  1 
3         Dave        country     2014-01-22  23.0000  3 
4         Tim         rock        2014-01-22  25.0000  1 
5         Dave        rock        2014-01-21  30.0350  2 
6         John        rock        2014-03-24  23.0000  1 
7         Stan        rap         2013-01-21  14.0000  1 
8         Jake        country     2014-01-21  30.0000  1 
9         Mike        country     2014-01-22  22.9995  3 
10        Jodi        country     2015-01-22  23.0006  1 
11        Jodi        country     2015-01-22  23.0004  3
```

Please help: this is probably super easy for a SQL expert. Remember the entire timestamp doesn't need to match, i.e. the hour:minute:second. it just needs to be the same yyyy-mm-dd

actually after reviewing this. I think that same_day_count column is ambiguous. however, the channels are going to differ and be unique enough that I believe it will give accurate results as long as it is actually possible to do this in SQL

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: using oracle. not sure version. I can find out though if needed

Comment: Why does Id `10` not match with `11? They are within .0005

Answer (score 1):

As you have phrased the query, you can do it with a correlated subquery (standard SQL so should work in any database):

```
select r.*,
       (select count(*)
        from records r2
        where r2.genre = r.genre and r2.date = r.date and
              abs(r2.channel - r.channel) <= 0.0005
       ) as same_day_count
from records r;
```

EDIT:

I notice that you are "chaining" the differences (row 11 has a value of 3 rather than 2).  This makes it a little more challenging.  Depending on how accurate you need to be, you may be able to just round the channel to 0.001 and use that value with equality.  This works for your sample data, but it may not be what you are looking for.

If you need to combine 0.0000, 0.0004, 0.0008, and 0.0012 into a single group, then the values need to be chained together.  You can do this by getting the beginning of each sequence using a subquery, doing a cumulative sum of that value, and then counting within each group where this value is constant:

```
select r.*, count(*) over (partition by genre, date, grp)
from (select r.*,
             sum(isStart) over (partition by genre, date order by channel) as grp
      from (select r.*,
                   (case when abs(channel - lag(channel) over (partition by genre, date order by channel) ) <=  0.0005
                         then 1 else 0 
                    end) as isStart
            from records r
           ) r
     ) r
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon Linoff. I am going to try using your first query. Here is another issue that came up. It turns out that I need to do this query on another 'select' instead of on an actual table. So the 'records' table is actually another select statement. How do I express that? Your query uses 'records' twice, and I don't want to have to do the select twice, because it is very big and would not be very efficient. sorry to change it up on you.

Comment: You would use a CTE . . . `with records as (<subquery here>) . . .`.

Answer (score 0):

How about using an analytic function, something like this:

```
with record as (select 1 id, 'Scott' name, 'rock' genre, to_date('2014-01-21', 'yyyy-mm-dd') dt, '30.0345' Channel from dual union all
                select 2 id, 'Jim' name, 'rap' genre, to_date('2014-01-21', 'yyyy-mm-dd') dt, '55.0000' Channel from dual union all
                select 3 id, 'Dave' name, 'country' genre, to_date('2014-01-22', 'yyyy-mm-dd') dt, '23.0000' Channel from dual union all
                select 4 id, 'Tim' name, 'rock' genre, to_date('2014-01-22', 'yyyy-mm-dd') dt, '25.0000' Channel from dual union all
                select 5 id, 'Dave' name, 'rock' genre, to_date('2014-01-21', 'yyyy-mm-dd') dt, '30.0350' Channel from dual union all
                select 6 id, 'John' name, 'rock' genre, to_date('2014-03-24', 'yyyy-mm-dd') dt, '23.0000' Channel from dual union all
                select 7 id, 'Stan' name, 'rap' genre, to_date('2013-09-16', 'yyyy-mm-dd') dt, '14.0000' Channel from dual union all
                select 8 id, 'Jake' name, 'country' genre, to_date('2014-01-21', 'yyyy-mm-dd') dt, '30.0000' Channel from dual union all
                select 9 id, 'Mike' name, 'country' genre, to_date('2014-01-22', 'yyyy-mm-dd') dt, '22.9995' Channel from dual union all
                select 10 id, 'Jodi' name, 'country' genre, to_date('2015-01-22', 'yyyy-mm-dd') dt, '23.0006' Channel from dual union all
                select 11 id, 'Jodi' name, 'country' genre, to_date('2015-01-22', 'yyyy-mm-dd') dt, '23.0004' Channel from dual)
select r.*,
       to_number(channel) - .0005 ch_minus,
       to_number(channel) + .0005 ch_plus,
       count(*) over (partition by dt order by to_number(channel)
                      range between .0005 preceding and .0005 following) cnt
from   record r;

        ID NAME  GENRE   DT         CHANNEL   CH_MINUS    CH_PLUS        CNT
---------- ----- ------- ---------- ------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         7 Stan  rap     2013-09-16 14.0000    13.9995    14.0005          1
         8 Jake  country 2014-01-21 30.0000    29.9995    30.0005          1
         1 Scott rock    2014-01-21 30.0345     30.034     30.035          2
         5 Dave  rock    2014-01-21 30.0350    30.0345    30.0355          2
         2 Jim   rap     2014-01-21 55.0000    54.9995    55.0005          1
         9 Mike  country 2014-01-22 22.9995     22.999         23          2
         3 Dave  country 2014-01-22 23.0000    22.9995    23.0005          2
         4 Tim   rock    2014-01-22 25.0000    24.9995    25.0005          1
         6 John  rock    2014-03-24 23.0000    22.9995    23.0005          1
        11 Jodi  country 2015-01-22 23.0004    22.9999    23.0009          2
        10 Jodi  country 2015-01-22 23.0006    23.0001    23.0011          2
```

My results don't match yours, but then yours don't seem to match the input data (row with id=5's channel changes between your input and output data, for example!)

Comment: thanks. I will try this. however, I don't think you accounted for the genres to be the same. where do I add that?

Comment: Add that into the partition by clause. (If you haven't worked with analytic functions before, I highly recommend you learn about them - they're incredibly powerful!). You can think of the partition by clause as similar to the group by clause in aggregate queries.